# How can I get output item set from FP-Growth or Apriori algorithm in Weka?

Tags: weka

when I run the apriori or FP-growth algorithm in weka. the output is showing the rules, not item set. anyone tell me how can I get the output.

Answer (score 2):

Click on (1) -not on the button-, a dialog box will pop up; then choose selection-field "outputItemsets", set it to "true".

Then right-click on (2) and save the window content (= the "result buffer") to a .txt file.

[image: screenshot]